# Azure Key Vault and Managed Identity - local development with REST

Tags: php, azure, token, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have a php application hosted in Azure VM, with some secrets in Key Vault. I have set up a Managed Identity and given access to the vault.

So my application can successfully get secrets from the vault, using a token obtained from Azure Instance Metadata Service (AIMS 169.254.169.254).

Azure SDK for php does not support Key Vault, so I am using the REST interface.

My problem is when running locally, i.e. my code running on desktop in VSCode, I cannot call AIMS to get a token as I don't have a Managed Identity on my local machine.

Only two options I can think of:

- developers create an environment variable to hold the secret, or
- include a localSettings file in my code, with a setting to store the secret

Then i can determine if the code is running locally, and if so, read the secret from this environment variable or localSettings.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Note that Visual Studio provides the AzureServiceTokenProvider(), which uses the credentials of the logged in user to get a token. But unfortunately this isn't available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way was to use an environment variable locally - which the code falls back to if for any reason the connection to the key vault fails

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, we have no way to use Azure MSI to develop PHP application on locally. So if you want to access Azure key vault on locally, I suggest you use a service principal to access Azure Key vault on local. The detailed steps are as below.
1. Create a service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n <your-application-name> --skip-assignment
az keyvault set-policy --name <your-key-vault-name> --spn $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --secret-permissions backup delete get list purge recover restore set
```

2. Get the Azure AD access token

```
Method : Post
Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{directoryId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:
     grant_type=client_credentials
     client_id=<>
     client_secret=<>
     scope=https://vault.azure.net/.default
```

3. Call the [key vault rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
   For example
   GET Secret

```
Method: GET
Url: {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version=7.0
Header: Authorization : Bearer <access token>
```

For more details, please refer to the [blog](https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-azure-key-vault-secret-through-azure-key-vault-rest-api-using-an-azure-ad-app-4d837fed747).